# Please give me some info about modify jftp code

Tags: directory, sftp

The use case is when a user logged in, the remote directory should direct to his own home directory rather than the root directory.
For example, when Tom logged in, the target directory should be /class12/boy/Tom, and Marry logged in, the directory should be /class12/girl/Marry, rather than /class12.
I do not know which part do I need to modify, I downloaded the source code from http://j-ftp.sourceforge.net/.
Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jftp looks like an ftp client:

> In short: JFtp is a graphical Java
>   network and file transfer client.

However, the behavior you desire can only be handled on the server side. EG, for SFTP (over SSH), you need to look into some kind of **chroot** or **jail**. For FTP, most daemons usually allow you to configure the paths your user can access, so you would edit the ftpd config file appropriately and restart the ftpd process.

If you do not have access to the server, then you will need to contact your server administrator / provider to make the necessary arrangements.

Comment: No problem, if you like feel free to edit / update your question with more information or start a new question with the server details (if you need additional assistance in setting this up).

Comment: But why when I use winSCP to log in, it will direct to my own directory, while I use this jftp just direct to the root directory? I do nothing on the server side.

Comment: It's possible to configure winSCP with a start path for the saved connection profile. Are you able to browse / (root) after logging in? I guess I read your question as limiting the logged in user to certain sub-directory vs just starting there. However, since jFTP is a browser-based client, the same options might not be available/feasible as in a stand-alone application like winSCP.

Comment: Yeah, I can go back to the root directory by winSCP after login.